# How to store html data in a pandas cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to be able to store html in a pandas data cell (so like the full page as a string, no conversion) but for some reason the html get's partially stripped and the string is broken down in multiple cells.

Any idea why this happens and how I could avoid this? My wanted outcome is just one single data cell containing the full html set.

I'm forced to use pandas because that is the default interface for my app when using python.

What I have is (very simplified) like this :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
url = 'http://somewhere.on.the.web'


def get_page():
    r= requests.get(url)
    return r.text

def rm_main(data):
    page = pd.DataFrame([get_page()])
    return page
```

and my outcome (page return) is like :

```
row 1 : <script type='text/javascript'> ... -->
row 2 : <meta http-equiv='x-dns-prefetch-control' content='on'>....
loads of additional rows
```

While I need all of my text as one single row in the output.
Any ideas?

Comment: Any way you can make a reproducible example? Like a small `r.text` that generates a `df` like in your outcome?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it's a bit of black box. The application I use has the possibility to use python as an external provider in it's own workflows, but everything is handled as a pandas data frame. So in some way I'm trying to find a hack to get a whole page returned in one cell, rather than nice rows and cells as expected by the tool. Now I save the file in practice, and re-import it later, but I'd like to skip that step.